# Java - Write in a Json with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, overwrite

I'm currently doing a project for school and I'm trying to write an object at the end of my json file (in the cards attribute) without rewriting everything using the Jackson library.

The problem is that when I try to do this my object is written correctly, but it is written at the end of the file, and I try to put it in the list of cards [ THERE ].

someone have an idea ? Thanks.

EDIT : I already know how to write to a file by rewriting it, for answer to my teacher's instructions I need to do it without rewriting the file.

**My Json File :**

```
{

  "cards": [
    {
      "subject": "The Earth",
      "questions": [
        {
          "challenge": "What is the highest mountain of the world?",
          "answer": "Everest"
        },
        {
          "challenge": "What is the largest ocean in the world?",
          "answer": "Pacific Ocean"
        }
      ],
      "author": "Roger",
      "theme": "IMPROBABLE"
    },

    {
      "subject": "Holidays",
      "questions": [
        {
          "challenge": "What is the most touristic country in the world?",
          "answer": "France"
        },
        {
          "challenge": "In 2019, how many pictures did vacationers take per day?",
          "answer": "55"
        }
      ],
      "author": "Roger",
      "theme": "PLEASURE"
    }
    
  ]

}
```

**My class Main :**

```
public class Main {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Question question1 = new Question("Roger", Theme.SCHOOL, "Test", "c1", "a1");
    Question question2 = new Question("Roger", Theme.SCHOOL, "Test", "c2", "a2");

    BasicCard bc = new BasicCard("Roger", Theme.SCHOOL, "Test", Arrays.asList(question1,question2));
    
    try {
          File file = new File(Constants.DECK_PATH);
          FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);

          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          SequenceWriter seqWriter = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValues(fileWriter);
          seqWriter.write(bc);
          seqWriter.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }

}
```

**Result**

```
{

  "cards": [
    {
      "subject": "The Earth",
      "questions": [
        {
          "challenge": "What is the highest mountain of the world?",
          "answer": "Everest"
        },
        {
          "challenge": "What is the largest ocean in the world?",
          "answer": "Pacific Ocean"
        }
      ],
      "author": "Roger",
      "theme": "IMPROBABLE"
    },

    {
      "subject": "Holidays",
      "questions": [
        {
          "challenge": "What is the most touristic country in the world?",
          "answer": "France"
        },
        {
          "challenge": "In 2019, how many pictures did vacationers take per day?",
          "answer": "55"
        }
      ],
      "author": "Roger",
      "theme": "PLEASURE"
    }
  ]
}{
  "subject" : "Test",
  "questions" : [ {
    "challenge" : "c1",
    "answer" : "a1"
  }, {
    "challenge" : "c2",
    "answer" : "a2"
  }, {
    "challenge" : "c3",
    "answer" : "a3"
  }, {
    "challenge" : "c4",
    "answer" : "a4"
  } ],
  "author" : "Damien",
  "theme" : "SCHOOL"
}
```

Comment: You can make a new class that represent the fields of the json. You can then read the json file and use the objectMapper to convert the json to your object. After this you can add cards to the list and use the objectMapper again to serialize your object to json.

Comment: But the file is rewritten that way. I would like to insert my element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the separation between two layers:

1. The filesystem, in your case provided through `FileWriter`
2. The logical layer (json), in your case provided through Jackson (`ObjectMapper`)

You currently append on the lower layer (`1. The filesystem`). This layer doesn't know that you're going to write json. It doesn't even know what json is. It simply let's you append more bytes to the end of an existing file.

What you want is to append to a existing json structure. To do so, you have to read in the existing object, append the desired object to it and replace the file completely by writing the updated object to the filesystem.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Question question1 = new Question("Roger", Theme.SCHOOL, "Test", "c1", "a1");
        Question question2 = new Question("Roger", Theme.SCHOOL, "Test", "c2", "a2");

        BasicCard bc = new BasicCard("Roger", Theme.SCHOOL, "Test", Arrays.asList(question1,question2));
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        File file = new File(Constants.DECK_PATH);

        try {
            // read the existing object from the file
            Map<String, List<BasicCard>> object = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<BasicCard>>>(){});
            // append your BasicCard bc to the list
            object.computeIfAbsent("cards", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(bc);
            
            // override the contents of the file by writing the object entirely again
            mapper.writeValue(file, object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do precisely is not to rewrite everything. Is there not another way?

Comment: If your object is this small (everything below 5 megabytes I would say) -> dont overcomplicate this. Yes, there are ways to work more efficient on the filesystem (not replacing the whole object every time) ... but theyre not worth the hassle unless you're doing this in a tight loop or handling with very big files

Comment: I know, but it's an instruction from my teacher, not a choice

Comment: The easiest way would be to drop the pretty-printing (each Card-Object is printed in a single line). Then you could simply append one line per card. Note that the file as a whole would then not be valid json. Each line in that file would be a valid json object, but the file as a whole not. 

Another but much more advanced way would be to look for a library that is able to work directly on the Filesystem, without reading in the existing object. One where you can specify your "target" via JSONpath-syntax or similar and lets you add to an existing structure directly on the file.

Comment: I just googled a bit and found a command-line tool called `jq`. There are java-wrappers using JNI built around it. It looks like jq is able to do what you want using a command like `jq .cards += {.. your json card object ..}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to append the json to existing file.

```
void write() {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
    ObjectNode original = om.readValue(new File("oldFile.json"), ObjectNode)

    Subject s = new Subject(List.of(new Question("c1", "a1"),
                             new Question("c2", "a2")), "Test")

    original.set("questions", om.valueToTree(s))

    om.writeValue(new File("newFile.json"), original)
}
```

Comment: I already know how to write to a file by rewriting it, for answer to my teacher's instructions I need to do it without rewriting the file.

Comment: either way the file will be rewritten or new file will be re-created. I am not totally sure .. but I think the tools like JQ will validate the whole file and recreate temp files before you can append something to the end

Comment: a hack can be to consider the original json as plain text file, replace the last `}` with the comma `,` your new json part followed by `}`